# mach_star and app store

Tags: app-store, osx-snow-leopard

Would there be any problems with sending an Mac app to App Store if it is using mach_star for code injection? Would apple approve this app and are there any apps in Mac App Store using mach_star?  Thanks in advance.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because [we're not customer support for your favorite company](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/255745/559745).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is an unofficial check list ([AppStore Checklist](http://www.makayama.com/checklist.html)) with item 25 about interpreted code. It is not the exact thing you mentioned but it might be the reason to reject your app.

Comment: Is there any way to ensure if app wil be rejected or no. Code injection is very time consuming, so I want to be sure that app will be approved before starting to do that.

Comment: Unfortunately, I haven't heard of any way to ensure the approval. A lot of success stories about "non-conforming" apps though (the ones which use "apple-like" interfaces). I guess you should also check the app with some antivirus software and see if it finds something.

Comment: You're not allowed to use private or even undocumented API calls in the App Store. It would be hard to imagine Apple allowing application to inject code into other processes in that light. The process/application isolation is an important security feature for Apple which they are pushing heavily. Some applications might be able to slip through the review process but then you'll never know when you'll get kicked out again.

Comment: I think dropbox use mach_star to developed their application.